# How to inject generic type in angular constructor that has a constraint

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a DataSource implementation that I use to populate a table of Angular Material. Because I'm going to reuse this class I want to make it generic.

```js
@Injectable()
export class TableDataSource<T, U extends TableService<T>> implements DataSource<T> {
  constructor(private dataService: U) {
  }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<T[]> {
    return new Observable<T[]>();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    //
  }
}
```

The component that is using this DataSource is receiving it via the constructor as well, injected; like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'myapp-divisions',
  templateUrl: './divisions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./divisions.component.scss'],
  providers: [TableDataSource]
})
export class DivisionsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private divisionDataSource: TableDataSource<DivisionData, DivisionsService>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I can't figure out what to do to fix the error below. The class `TableDataSource` is already decorated with `@Injectable()` so I think I have to "configure a different provider" somehow? My knowledge about this is too limited but I do feel this is the cleanest way to go.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
          ERROR in src/app/myapp/divisions/table-data-source.service.ts:22:23 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'dataService' of class 'TableDataS
ource'.
    Found U

          22   constructor(private dataService: U) {
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
          src/app/myapp/divisions/divisions.component.ts:17:15 - error NG2005: The class 'TableDataSource' cannot be created via dependency injection, as it does not have
 an Angular decorator. This will result in an error at runtime.

    Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'TableDataSource', or configure a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory').


          17   providers: [TableDataSource]
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

            src/app/myapp/divisions/table-data-source.service.ts:8:1
                8 @Injectable()
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                9 export class TableDataSource<T, U extends TableService<T>> implements DataSource<T> {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              ...
               81   // }
                  ~~~~~~
               82 }
                  ~
              'TableDataSource' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work that way. Angular has no way of knowing what to inject in the constructor. The error given is a bit wrong though. Generics are ignored in the whole dependency injection process. You can however do the following:

```
providers: [
  TableDataSource,
  { provide: TableService, useExisting: DivisionsService }
]
```

and add the `Injectable` to your `DivisionsService` like this

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DivisionsService extends TableService<DivisionData> {}
```

and remove it from `TableService` and make it abstract:

```
export abstract class TableService<T> {}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxzv2w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Perfect! I don't mind providing the service like this. The question for me is: is this the neatest way to accomplish this; decoupling , reusable code, etc

Comment: @321X even though i've never done it like this, I think it's a pretty neat way of doing it. And yes, I fixed the typo :)